# How Do You Add an Image in DialogFlow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

How in the world do you add an image to a chatbot for Dialogflow CX? I can't get this to save my time.

I have the image I want on LinkedIn, Canva, Pinterest and I have it on Google photos. The problem is that every code I look at has a .png or jpg ending, None of the links I have when I get link address give me that.

**Where are people putting their photos to get the links to upload to DialogFlow CX and how the heck do you put the image in there?**

I am thoroughly confused by this and hella frustrated.

PLEASE HELP! SOMEBODY! ANYBODY!

Why couldn't these developers make this simple. SMDH!

Comment: Have you read the [image section](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#image_response_type) of the Dialogflow Messenger documentation?